# Cognos 10 Crosstab filter on individual column

Tags: filter, crosstab, cognos-10

I have searched but cant seem to find my specific problem.

I struggling to put a filter on a column in a crosstab where two columns use the same data. They both use the data Project Count but one requires the filter to view only active projects. (In our data we have a predefined filter for viewing active projects.)  Can you help please I'm fairly new to cognos so a thorough explanation would be greatly appreciated.

### | <#Project Count#>   | <#Project Count#>

<#Project Manager#>       |  <#1234#>           |  <#1234#>

Comment: Is the data source relational or dimensional (DB or cube)?

Comment: As far as I can see it is cube

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to do the following:

Create two crosstabs in your report - one with the Active Project filter, one without. This will also create the queries you need, 'behind the scenes'.

In the Query Explorer, click on Queries - this opens the Query pane.
Drag a 'join' from the toolbox into the query explorer. In the two blank spaces for the join, drag in each of the queries that were created for the crosstabs. Double click on the join and create a link between Project Manager in each query.

Now, double-click the query that is on the left of the join to edit the Query. Drag the Project Manager and Project Count from one of the queries in the Source pane, and the Project Count from the other query. Rename the appropriate query item to 'Active Project Count'.

Now, go back into the report view, select one of the crosstabs, and change the 'query' property to the name of the joined query that you just created. You should be able to drag 'Active Project Count' in beside the existing 'Project Count' query item, from the middle tab of the Insertable Objects pane.

Once that's done, select the second crosstab, and cut (not delete) it from the report (deleting it would also remove the query, which you still need).

Comment: Done this but now both Count columns give me a total of 1 for each project manager instead of the true number. I checked that both tables gave the correct figures before I joined them. I have changed the relationship of the link between the two managers and this has not helped either (what should it be 1..1 = 1..1?). Any further suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Just came across your question though its quite old but the solution is same as suggested by Tethera until joining to create a link, and yeah, link relationship should be 1..1=1..1
Now once you are done with creating a joint query, go to the page & create a new crosstab & drag the data items from Joint query (query items can be reached in top right area between Source & Toolbox)..